# how to load content of one html file into another html file with all its scripts and styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i know that this question is asked many times here and i have read those answers but my question is bit longer than this. suppose there are two files: a.html and b.html, now:

- a.html contains all the scripts and styles that are common throughout
  the project and `<div>` tag for content.
- b.html contains only the codes required to load in the div tag of
  a.html file.
- there are some other scripts and styles required only for
  b.html.

  so, how do i load that page specific js and css with the page's content into the div of a.html??? and how to remove them when i call another c.html file's content with its own js and css files??
  Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with HTML Frames?

Answer (score 1):

use Jquery Ajax to load page 2 into the div ( follow below example)

**page 1(HTML)**

```
<div id="loadepage2here" ></div>
<div id="loadepage3here" ></div>
```

**page 1(js)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.get('/locationOfPage2.html',function(data){
     $("#loadepage3here").empty();
     $("#loadepage2here").html(data);
   });
 $.get('/locationOfPage3.html',function(data){
     $("#loadepage2here").empty();
     $("#loadepage3here").html(data);
   });
});
```

**Edit: as asked how to use only div for multiple page**

**page 1(HTML)**

```
<div id="loadepagehere" ></div>
<button onClick="loadPage('page1.html')" >Page 1</button >
<button  onClick="loadPage('page2.html')" >Page 2</button >
```

**page 1(js)**

```
loadPage(location)
{
    $.get(location,function(data){
       $("#loadepagehere").empty();
       $("#loadepagehere").html(data);
     });
}
```

Comment: will not load any javascripts or css from that particular page, except for they are inline, what is bad practice.

Comment: yes it will load exernal javascript and css also give it a try

Comment: ok but let say i have 100 pages. should i have to put 100 divs for that?? plus js?? i don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Why would you want to load 100 pages? If that need arises you might want to reconsider how data is fetched, consolidated, and presented.

Comment: @Terry i dont want to load 100 pages at the same time. what i am asking is if on clicking a link i am loading one page then on clicking another link i want to load another page but in the same div. i don't want to put another div for that.

Comment: then add only one div make the on success of ajax make that div empty and then put the data into its html (see the edit section in answer)

Comment: @AtalKishore you are 100% right. forget about 100 pages. if i have only 10 pages then also i have to write $.get method 10 times. can't it be done by applying some functional logic like declaring a function where i can pass some arguments like href attribute of anchor and load that page by ajax?? and what about .load() method?? can't we use that??

Comment: @VishalBhatt  See the solution in Edit section

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.js to achieve this. Below is the code snippet to achieve this.

```
    var dynamicHTML = $('#divLoadHTML');
    dynamicHTML.load('/Pages/Common/b.html')
    $compile(dynamicHTML.contents())($scope);
```

divHTML is a div on a.html page.